# How to download file without prompting program picker in IE11

Tags: html

I have the following HTML that works great to download files in Chrome and Firefox. I'm using angular to dynamically generate the file name and the UTF-8 body.

```
<a download="myfile.xls" href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8, (UTF-8 body 
string)">
   To Excel
</a>
```

The problem is that in IE11 it prompts a box "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer?"

Selecting Allow prompts the Win 10 program picker "You'll need a new app to open this data" with the only option being to search the windows store for an application. When Excel is clearly installed and is the default for the file when navigating through the file system.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you are trying to tell it is xls, but it is not according to the mime type, so a warning is in order

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the search term I think I've found something helpful! So would it be more proper for it to be formatted as `data:application/vnd.ms-excel` ?

Comment: Try it and see :)

Comment: Trial and error is tough because I can't get excel onto my developer VM and it's a ~5 minute build/release process to get it deployed to our development servers.That said - making that change still gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(